# panna cotta gelatine and size/form

Tags: dessert, italian-cuisine, cream, gelatine

Suppose I've found my "sweet spot" for the amount of gelatine for a recipe of panna cotta which has been tried only for individual portions that are either turned upside down on a plate or topped and served directly in the glass.

If I were to make a bigger loaf to be sliced, how would I need to change the amount of gelatine? Would it be a good idea to increase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

- If your current “sweet spot” percentage gives you a panna cotta that’s sturdy enough to hold up on its own, so that you can make clean “cuts” with your spoon, you are fine also in larger shapes.
- If your preferred ratio is rather soft and creamy, so that the upside-down servings sag significantly, go up. Of course it won’t be as creamy and melty as before, you are making it more solid on purpose.

Only you know how your recipe turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I would suggest you calculate the percent of gelatin that you use; that is, to the entire liquid mixture.  Then, for a larger batch plug in your percentage and use that new amount.

Comment: That's not what I was asking :) if my sweet spot for glass pannacotta is, say, 1% should I keep this 1%for a loaf or I increase it?

Comment: Well, then, I think I answered your question anyway.  Yes.  If your sweet spot is 1% of 500 ml. then it would be 1% of 1000 ml. ...etc.

Comment: Question was indeed whether the bigger the form the more gelatine makes sense to use for structure purposes

Comment: I hear you.  I am suggesting that the percentage of gelatin does not change (of course, the amount changes).